# Excel 2010 VBA Function paste as values after calculating

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I'm using this web scraping VBA code in Excel 2010 to pull the title off of web pages.  I want  it to paste the title as values after the code has run.

Here's my code:

```
Function GetTitleFromURL(sURL As String)
Dim wb As Object
Dim doc As Object

Set wb = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

wb.Navigate sURL

While wb.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend

GetTitleFromURL = wb.Document.Title

wb.Quit

Set wb = Nothing

'trying to paste as value after get title
'Application.CutCopyMode = False
'    Selection.Copy
'    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
'        :=False, Transpose:=False

End Function
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: are you trying to run this like a UDF? If so, you won't be able to perform operations on XL that way.

Comment: I don't know, what's UDF?

Comment: UDF = `User Defined Function` that is, where you call a VBA function from a cell on a worksheet, like this `=GetTitleFromURL("www.MyUrl.com")`. If you are calling it from other VBA code then its OK (but not well designed for that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this may be suitable?

```
Sub GetTitleFromURL()

  Dim source_wb As Object
  Dim target_wb As Object
  Dim target_sheet As Object
  Dim title As String
  Dim sURL As String

 Set target_wb = ActiveWorkbook
  Set target_sheet = target_wb.ActiveSheet

  sURL = target_sheet.Range("A1").Value
    Set source_wb = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
      source_wb.Navigate sURL
        While source_wb.Busy
          DoEvents
       Wend
     title = source_wb.Document.title
  source_wb.Quit

 target_sheet.Range("B1").Value = title

 Set source_wb = Nothing
   Set target_sheet = Nothing
 Set target_wb = Nothing

End Sub
```